# How to access a combobox inside a Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, treeview, wpf-controls

I have a treeview inside which i have defined a combobox . i want to access the combobox selected item in the SelectionChanged event in code behind.How to access it ?

```
<TreeView Name="treeview" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding treeviewItems }" 
        MinHeight="300" Width="200">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <ComboBox Name="cmbbox1" Width="100"Height="25"     
                SelectionChanged="cmbbox1_SelectionChanged" / >
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

I am not able to access cmbbox1in the code behind ..What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Try with FindResource method (ex: treeView.FindResource(cmbbox1)).

Comment: its not working . Error is cmbbox1 doesnot exists in the current context.

Comment: Hi,FindResource method with accept only string so please use like (treeview.FindResource("cmbbox1") as ComboBox;) also add key to Combobox x:Key="cmbbox1" to access it

Comment: i am not able to set X:KEY  value. IS there any other method ?

Comment: Why any problem?you got any error or exceptions?

<TreeView Name="treeview" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding treeviewItems }" 
        MinHeight="300" Width="200">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <ComboBox x:Key="cmbbox1" Name="cmbbox1" Width="100"Height="25"     
                SelectionChanged="cmbbox1_SelectionChanged" / >
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>

Comment: I tried the same..Its showing an error .Key attribute can be used only in a tag contained in IDictionary type property